# Get places in radius of a certain point using SQL geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, geocoding, geospatial

I have an SQL table column with the Geography type:

```
create table dbo.Events
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Events_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Localization geography not null
);
```

How can I get all events in a radius of 40 km? Is this possible?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you have latitude and longitude of the point from which you want to search:

```
DECLARE @Origin GEOGRAPHY,
        -- distance defined in meters
        @Distance INTEGER = 40000;        

-- center point
SET @Origin = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.084039 37.42227)', 4326);

-- return all rows from events in 40km radius
SELECT * FROM dbo.Events WHERE @Origin.STDistance(Localizaton) <= @Distance;
```

Comment: Instead of using STGeoFromText I would just do "SET @Origin = geography::Point(-34.5923540,138.7460620,4326)"

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326); --set here GPS from where you want to search 40 km
SELECT Localization.STDistance(@h) from dbo.events
```

The result of STDistance() will be in meters.