# How to calculate the bounding box for a given lat/lng location and querying the database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, geocoding

I have given a location defined by latitude and longitude. Now i want to calculate a bounding box within e.g. 500 meters of that point.

The bounding box should be defined as `latmin`, `lngmin` and `latmax`, `lngmax`.

My database has almost 152.000 records ( locations of objects defined by lat long), and if the user enters the specific object in the search bar (search by name), I should find objects to the specific radius e.g. within 500 meters.

For example this is one record: `Latitude = 41.72213058512578, Longitude = 44.77684020996094, Name = company1`

If I find `latmin`, `lngmin` and `latmax`, `lngmax` how to query the database? I want to achieve this in C#.

Comment: `var query = yourContext.Where(x => x.Latitude >= latmin && x.Latitude > latmin <= latmax && x.Longitude >= lngmin && x.Longitude <= lngmax);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560832/get-places-in-radius-of-a-certain-point-using-sql-geography

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Haversine Formula.

Create this query in your application or Stored Procedure from your database. It will return the 15 closest locations to given latpoint and longpoint within a given radius. The radius is now set to 50 feel free to change that.

```sql
 SELECT z.zip,
        z.primary_city,
        z.latitude, z.longitude,
        p.distance_unit
                 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(z.longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))) AS distance_in_meters
  FROM zip AS z
  JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
        SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint,
                50.0 AS radius,      111054.0 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p ON 1=1
  WHERE z.latitude
     BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND z.longitude
     BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
  ORDER BY distance_in_meters
  LIMIT 15
```

change 111054.0 to 69.0 for distance_in_miles

Something like this in your C# application to call a stored procedure and get the data back from the query in a list.

```
private List<DataModel> getData(double latitude, double longitude, int radius)
{ 
    SqlParameter[] param = 
                     {
                        new SqlParameter("@lat", latitude),
                        new SqlParameter("@lon", longitude),
                        new SqlParameter("@rad", radius)
                     };          
  //Call stored procedure
  var data db.Database.SqlQuery<DataModel("Haversine",param)
  return data.ToList();
}
```

Comment: think this is an overkill, and whats with the 69 comment?

Comment: Change the number 111054.0 to 69.0 to return distance from origin in miles like it says.